# How to merge duplicated rows into single row using SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I've thousands of duplicate (ids) rows in SQL table but the other columns are different. I want to merge duplicate rows with respect to ids. Here is the sample.

Here is my table with duplicated rows.

```
id2     Name
50300   NAJMA BAIGUM
50300   MUHAMMAD IQBAL
50301   WAHABUDDIN
50301   ABDUL SALAM
```

What I want after merging into 1 row of corresponding duplicated id2 using sql query?

```
id2      Name       Name
50300   NAJMA BAIGUM    MUHAMMAD IQBAL
50301   WAHABUDDIN  ABDUL SALAM
```

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: Never more than two rows per id?

Comment: No, It can be more than 2 rows per id

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 0):

How about array_agg and group_by ?

```
SELECT id2, array_agg(name) FROM mysterious_table GROUP BY id2
```

Comment: No luck. showing an error "Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 21
'array_agg' is not a recognized function name."

Comment: And have you tried the link from Tim Biegeleisen in the comments above ?

Comment: Tried, showing the error "Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 24
'group_concat' is not a recognized function name."

Comment: yes i didn't recognize the sql-2000-server tag so array_agg is not present, which means there is no easy solution. please follow the link from Tim Biegeleisen to find a workaround

Comment: I've achieved this in Mysql after migration of rows from SQL Server 2000 to MySQL.